# Netbeans - find used members of an imported class within a java source file

Tags: java, netbeans

Does Netbeans provide a way to find all method, field and constructor usages of a specific imported class (or one that does not need an explicit import statement) within the scope of a single java source file?

So, for a source file along the lines of pseudo code below, find all usages of `Foo`s members:

```java
package org.so;

import org.so.Foo;

public class Bar {
  void usageExample(Foo foo) {
    if (Foo.CONSTANT == foo.someMethod()) {
    }
  }
}
```

Usually one searches for a specific member of `Foo` (or usages of `Foo` itself), but that is not applicable to my case. I'd like to find usages such as `Foo.CONSTANT` and `foo.someMethod()` *within the same search*, since both `CONSTANT` and `someMethod()` are members of `Foo` and are used within the search scope (source file that contains class `Bar`).

I'm trying to find an easy way to get a list of all method calls that potentially mutate the state of a specific class of objects, but a list of all method calls would suffice to narrow down the possibilities.

This question is about a programming tool, not about how to implement such functionality.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable thing to want to do, but I don't know how to do it in NetBeans, or any other IDE. A very crude alternative approach might be to simply comment out the import of `Foo` in `Bar.java` and then review the compilation errors arising. (I realize that is not what you are looking for at all - I'm just trying to think of something else that might help.)

Comment: @skomisa, unfortunately, commenting out the import has a similar effect as Find Usages of `Foo`. At least in Netbeans, it only underlines explicit occurrences of the missing symbol. I ended up resorting to a manual approach (scrolling through raw source code).

Comment: OK. Another possibility is to use a third party code analyzer. You have to pay for a some of them, but others have a free trial, or are completely free. You might want to look at [SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org/features/issues-tracking/). I haven't tried it but it looks like it's free, and there's a plugin for NetBeans, [radar-netbeans](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/51532/radar-netbeans) which even works with NetBeans 11.0/JDK 11.

Comment: You should also file a request for that: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/  - not sure how big the chances are that someone implements that, but at least the wish is recorded

Comment: Just to expand on the comment from @a_horse_with_no_name, you could even [volunteer to write the code change in NetBeans yourself](https://netbeans.apache.org/participate/submit-pr.html)! The process for adding fixes and enhancements to NetBeans is similar to that for any other Apache project.